# Angular 4.3 XSRF HttpClientModule

Tags: angular

I'm implementing CSRF protection within my angular project. I've upgraded to 4.3, and according to HttpClientModule docs at:

https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection

I have to implement,

```
 HttpClientXsrfModule.withConfig({
cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
  }),
```

I've done so, however the compiler complains:

Property 'withConfig' does not exist on type 'typeof HttpClientXsrfModule'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is a typing issue in the documentation.

You need to use "withOptions" instead.

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
  headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
})
```